# Geckofx - Recording Remote Video in WebRTC

Tags: c#, webrtc, video-recording, geckofx

I have implemented video chatting using WebRTC for Mozilla Firefox.
Now I want to record video and audio.
So I used MediaStreamRecorder.js library to record video and audio.
It works good in Mozilla Firefox.

Then I opened the same page using GeckoFX browser in c# windows form application.
It records audio good successfully but fails to record video.

How can I record both video and audio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't why geckofx don't support video record.

Using ffmpeg to record video.

Snapshot video every times, using ffmpeg generate a video from snapshots in the end of recording.
Sometimes audio and video are not synchronized.
But this method is good.